# When i use Waterline's create method, it doesn't return the new record's ID

Tags: mysql, sails.js, mariadb, waterline

When i create a new record using Waterline's create method, the created object is returned, but without it's ID. How can I get the id of the last inserted object?

I'm using the mysql adapter on mariadb if it makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're probably doing something wrong. I have not done any additional configuration to waterline, anyway it returns `id` every time when I use `new` query as well as record at all.

In most cases I don't create `id` field in sails model, auto-generation works quite fine for me. If you create `id` field by yourself ensure that it has correct configuration. [This issue shows](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/481) that id requires to be

```
autoIncrement: true
```

otherwise it really don't return id with queries.

Full field should look like this:

```
id: {
    type: 'integer', 
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
}
```

Comment: Good find, Glen!

I tried the documented `autoPK: false` to no avail. The key was setting `autoIncrement: true`.

Comment: Interesting--`autoIncrement: true` is the default.  I wonder if you had it set otherwise in your global `config/models.js` file?

Comment: @sgress454 I guess this is default when not specifying `id` attribute in model at all. While adding this, it seems like sails engine reset all defaults for it. This maybe the OP problem. Anyway this is just my guess, I am not sure about it