# Sails.js ID not returned on Model.create()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

js and am using MySQL along with it.

So in one of my controller I am trying to create a row, which is working fine but I was wondering why am I not getting back particularly the ***ID* of the row** along with other details.

Here's how my Model(Location) looks like

```
module.exports = {
    autoCreatedAt:false,
    autoUpdatedAt:false,

    attributes: {
        lat:{
            type: 'float',
            required: true
        },
        lng:{
            type: 'float',
            required: true
        },
        id: {
           type: 'integer', 
           primaryKey: true,
        }
    }
};
```

And my LocationController:

```
Locations.create(req.params.all(), function(err, loc){
    if(err) return res.negotiate(err)
    res.status(201);
    return res.json(loc);
})
```

The response am getting is:

```
{
  "lat": 19.075984,
  "lng": 72.877656
}
```

> I need the ID of the table row along with the lat and lng

Comment: Does the client need ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When i use Waterline's create method, it doesn't return the new record's ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103271/when-i-use-waterlines-create-method-it-doesnt-return-the-new-records-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Waterline ORM issues:

Please checkout https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/481 may be helpful

This is because you have the autoPK: false flag set. So you could either turn that back on and remove the id field from your attributes or add autoIncrement: true to the id attribute.

The autoPK flag builds an id attribute identical to what you are building:

id: {
    type: 'integer', 
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
}